# Can't find largest duplicate value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some multiple duplicate data in my table what I am trying to do I want to fetch only the largest values from the duplicate data.

I added an image for example from which I want to get only the last two row data because the first row's first column value is lower than the others and service ids are same I am trying to do this by counting the data but can't get the final result.

Currently I am using this query to count data

```
SELECT 
    ServiceId, COUNT(*) Count_Duplicate
FROM 
    TestDeleteTable
GROUP BY 
    ServiceId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work for you.

```
SELECT ServiceId,RowId FROM 
(
SELECT *, COUNT(ServiceId) OVER(PARTITION BY ServiceId ORDER BY ROWID) CT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ServiceId ORDER BY ROWID) RN
FROM TestDeleteTable
)T
WHERE T.RN> 1 AND T.CT > 1
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PPL24706)</kbd>**

Another approach can be

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT ServiceId, MIN(ROWID) M
 FROM TestDeleteTable 
 GROUP BY ServiceId
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT * FROM TestDeleteTable T
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM CTE C WHERE C.ServiceId=T.ServiceId AND T.ROWID > C.M
)
```

Or simply with a `INNER JOIN` with `CTE` like following.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT ServiceId, MIN(ROWID) MinValue, Count(ServiceId) CountService
 FROM @t 
 GROUP BY ServiceId
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT T.* FROM @T T
INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.ServiceId= C.ServiceId
WHERE C.CountService> 1 AND T.ROWID > C.MinValue
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for such nice and quick solution @PSK